# short syntax for type-dependent template

Tags: c++, templates

It is well know how to use some type-depent types using struct metaprogramming with specializations:

```cpp
    struct TypeOne {};
    struct TypeTwo {};

    template<typename T>
    struct TypeDependentType {};

    template<>
    struct TypeDependentType<int> {
        using dependent_type = TypeOne;
    };

    template<>
    struct TypeDependentType<double> {
        using dependent_type = TypeTwo;
    };

    template<typename T>
    struct ExampleTypeUse {};

    //now, use this dependent type:

    using Foo1 = TypeDependentType<int>::dependent_type; //declares Foo1 as synonym to TypeOne
    using Foo2 = TypeDependentType<double>::dependent_type; //declase Foo2 as synonym to TypeTwo

    //dependent type can also be used as template parameter in other template

    using Foo3 = ExampleTypeUse<TypeDependentType<int>::dependent_type>; //same as ExampleTypeUse<TypeOne>
    using Foo4 = ExampleTypeUse<TypeDependentType<double>::dependent_type>; // same as ExampleTypeUse<TypeTwo>
```

and with a `using` directive we can make these even more easily available:

```cpp
    template<typename T>
    using type_dependent_type = typename TypeDependentType<T>::dependent_type;

    using Foo5 = type_dependent_type<int>; //same as Foo1, but shorter
    using Foo6 = type_dependent_type<double>; //same as Foo2, but shorter
    using Foo7 = ExampleTypeUse<type_dependent_type<int>>; //same as Foo3, but shorter
    using Foo8 = ExampleTypeUse<type_dependent_type<double>>; //same as Foo4, but shorter
```

Now, if we go for type-dependent templates, we might have the following:

```cpp
    template<typename T> struct TemplateOne {};
    template<typename T> struct TemplateTwo {};

    template<typename T>
    struct TypeDependentTemplate {};

    template<>
    struct TypeDependentTemplate<int> {
        template<typename T>
        using dependent_template = TemplateOne<T>;
    };

    template<>
    struct TypeDependentTemplate<double> {
        template<typename T>
        using dependent_template = TemplateTwo<T>;
    };

    template<template<typename> typename T>
    struct ExampleTemplateUse {};


    template<typename T>
    using Boo1 = TypeDependentTemplate<int>::dependent_template<T>; //declares Boo1 as a template equivalent to TemplateOne

    template<typename T>
    using Boo2 = TypeDependentTemplate<double>::dependent_template<T>; //declares Boo2 as a template equivalent to TemplateTwo

    using Boo3 = ExampleTemplateUse<TypeDependentTemplate<int>::template dependent_template>;
    //declares Boo3 as ExampleTemplateUse<TemplateOne>

    using Boo4 = ExampleTemplateUse<TypeDependentTemplate<double>::template dependent_template>;
    //declares Boo4 as ExampleTemplateUse<TemplateTwo>
```

It would be nice to now have some `using` directive similar to the

```cpp
template<typename T>
using type_dependent_type = typename TypeDependentType<T>::dependent_type;
```

we saw earlier, so that we would have syntax that behaves more or less like:

```cpp
//not legal C++ (at least I assume so)
    template<typename T>
    using Boo5 = type_dependent_template<int><T>; //same as Boo1

    template<typename T>
    using Boo6 = type_dependent_template<double><T>; //same as Boo2

    using Boo7 = ExampleTemplateUse<type_dependent_template<int>>; //same as Boo3

    using Boo8 = ExampleTemplateUse<type_dependent_type<double>>; //same as Boo4
```

So, **is there some form of using directive that enables this easier access to the type-dependent template, enabling us to write syntax in the spirit of `Boo4,...,Boo8`?**

---

In particular, i would really love to be able to  write:

```cpp
ExampleTemplateUse<type_dependent_type<double>> my_obj;
```

Comment: Is there something wrong with `type_dependent_template<int, T>`?

Comment: for using the template right away: no. but if you want to pass the type-dependent-template as a template parameter to another struct (see Boo7, Boo8), then just leaving out the T will not suffice

Comment: There is no currying of class templates. IOW there is no way to create a template that directly "outputs" a template. No such thing as `x<y><z>`. You can have either `x<y,z>` or `x<y>::t<z>`.

Comment: well, then it just seems like there is not a way to exactly achieve what i want. `x<y>::t` will do the job for passing to another template, and `x<y,z>` will be good for directly using it.